# Getting sensor values per second

Tags: android, sensors, android-sensors

Is there any way that I can get the sensor reading per second? 
what is SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL rate in seconds?

```
sm=(SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
accelerometer=sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
sm.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

Comment: Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER
SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL 161ms 
SENSOR_DELAY_UI  20ms
SENSOR_DELAY_GAME 20ms
SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST 20ms but im not sure if i can change the value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The delay specified by SENSOR_DELAY_* is only a **suggested delay**, actual results might come faster or slower. If you only need one reading per second you can use the slowest rate (SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL), it should update about 5 times per second. You'll need your own timing if you want to do something exactly once per second, though.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html

Comment: sm.registerListener(this, accelerometer, 1000) will return the acceleration values per second?

Comment: Looks like you can set absolute values since API 11. So yes, this should fire approximately once per second. But anyway, don't expect this to be very precise.

Answer (score 7):

thank you, it answered my question, too, i was using 1000, seems like the values are in micro seconds.

```
 SENSOR_DELAY_UI      (60,000 microsecond delay)
 SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST (0 microsecond delay)
 SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL) (200,000 microseconds delay)
```

so for one second i should use a constant 1,000,000 micro seconds.

Comment: @Soner Gönül                                                                                    Does setting <SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL> to 1000000 really works?                                                                                                                 For me it still givs >20 records per second even with 1,000,000 as delay frequency value.                                                                                                     I had to finally do it introducing logic by aggregating all the sensor records for the second and averaging out them then for further use.

Comment: The docs says:

 The desired delay between two consecutive events in microseconds. This is only a hint to the system. Events may be received faster or slower than the specified rate. Usually events are received faster. Can be one of SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL, SENSOR_DELAY_UI, SENSOR_DELAY_GAME, SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST or the delay in microseconds.

Answer (score 0):

SENSOR_DELAY_UI      (60,000 microsecond delay)
SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST (0 microsecond delay)
SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL) (200,000 microseconds delay)